# Getting a Syntax Error while calling the function in PHP CODE

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been developing a website in wordpress and when i am fetching the functgions...the dbppwl_script() it response wbut when im trying to ru  the after theme functgion it shows an syntax error related to the fucntion after_theme

```
 <?php
//  theme function code 

function dbpplwp_theme_setup(){
    add_theme_support('custom-logo');
    add_theme_support('title-tag');
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size('home-featured', 680, 400, array('center','center'));
    add_theme_size('single-img', 600, 550, array('center','center'));
    add_thehe_support('automatic-feed-links');

    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => _('Primary Menu','dbpplwp')
    ));
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'dbpplwp_theme_setup' )

function dbpplwp_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style('style',get_stylesheet_uri() );
};
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dbpplwp_scripts');
?>
```

Can anybody tell what kind of error is recurring here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: This is not an awesome question title.

Answer (score 2):

You missed `;` Each statement must ends up with a semicolon in PHP.

missed here : `add_action('after_setup_theme', 'dbpplwp_theme_setup' )`

to

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'dbpplwp_theme_setup' );
```